# How to setup my bindingcontext for my xamarin.forms app with mvvm and sqlite

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

The basic of my app is that i have an AgendaPage which has a collectionview of items and when i click the add icon, i can fill a form to populate this collectionview.

My app was working when i didn't set my app MVVM style but i am trying to apply the MVVM logic to my app.

Currently if i set the BindingContext of my NewFormPage to Agenda() my NewFormPage opens when i click the add button BUT if i set my BindingContext to NewFormViewModel, nothing open up and my app crash so i am trying to figure out what i am doing wrong in setting up this MVVM.

Note: currently i only have a clicked function to open up the page ( didn't implement the command yet, i was trying to implement the save command).

**Agenda.cs in the database folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Calculette.Database;

namespace Calculette.Models
{
    [Table("Agenda")]
    public class Agenda
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**NewFormViewModel.cs in the ViewModel folder**

```
using Calculette.Database;
using Calculette.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Calculette.ViewModel
{
    class NewFormViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public Command AgendaSaveFormCommand { get; set; }


        public NewFormViewModel()
        {
            
            AgendaSaveFormCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveForm(), () => !IsBusy);
            
        }

        public string Topic
        {
            get => Topic;
            set
            {
                Topic = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string Duration
        {
            get => Duration;
            set
            {
                Duration = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get => Date;
            set
            {
                Date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                isBusy = value;

                //OnPropertyChanged();

                AgendaSaveFormCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public int ID { get; }

        async Task SaveForm()
        {
            
         IsBusy = true;
         await Task.Delay(4000);

            
           IsBusy = false;

            Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
            await App.Database.SaveAgendaAsync(agenda);

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
            
        }
    }
}
```

**NewFormPage.xaml.cs in the Views folder**

```
using Calculette.Models;
using Calculette.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Calculette.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewFormPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewFormPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
           // BindingContext = new Agenda();

            BindingContext = new NewFormViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

**AgendaPage.xaml in the views folder (xaml that calls Clicked that open NewFormPage**

```
<ImageButton Source="iconplus.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="GoToNewFormPage"></ImageButton>
```

**the GoToNewFormPage function in AgendaPage.xaml.cs**

```
protected async void GoToNewFormPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.NewFormPage());
}
```

Comment: please learn to use the debugger.  So many of the problems you have would be solved much more quickly if you knew how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all of your properties are implemented incorrectly

this will lead to an infinite recursive loop - `Duration` will call `Duration` will call `Duration`... until your app crashes

```
public string Duration
    {
        // this will just call the capital-D Duration property again
        // which will then call itself again, and again, and again
        get => Duration;
        set
        {
            // this will call the setter for the capital-D Duration property recursively
            Duration = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

you need to have a private backing field that is named differently than the property

```
private string duration;

public string Duration
    {
        get => duration;
        set
        {
            duration = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for answer this worked but the agenda added is always blank and doesn't have the good date any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: this is because `SaveForm` creates an empty `Agenda` object and then saves it without setting any of it's properties

Comment: Ok nice, just one last question why is my Date is initialized to a random date ( it doesn't take the DatePicker date when filling the form out) its just always 01 jan Thanks a lot.

Comment: it isn't random, that is the .NET default value for a DateTime

Comment: Yes, but isn't it supposed to take whatever the Date i pick in my DatePicker ? Since it's linked together by the Date value

Comment: if your DatePicker is correctly bound to your VM, the Date value of your VM should match the Picker.  But your Agenda object is not bound to anything, so you will need to manually set it to the value of the VM.

Comment: It's due to one of my old problem that i had fixed, if i put Date="{Binding Date}" in my xaml for my DatePicker, it will have the good selected Date BUT it ruins my old solution because the default Date becomes 01 jan 1900 when you want to select a date ( which is annoying for the user). I had this to fix it : Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}" but since i am using Binding now i can't have both so i have to somehow find a way to initialize my DatePicker to todays date which is weird because from the doc it says it should be initialized to todays date

Comment: if you are using binding, you need to initialize the property in your VM to the correct value (today's date).  In the constructor of your VM just do `this.Date = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 1):

You did not set value for the object's property when clicking on the add icon.

```
 async Task SaveForm()
    {
        
     IsBusy = true;
     await Task.Delay(4000);

        
       IsBusy = false;

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();

        //here you should set value of a blank object 
        Agenda.Topic = xx;
        Agenda.Date = xx;
        Agenda.Duration = xx;
        await App.Database.SaveAgendaAsync(agenda);

        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
        
    }
```